# res.download() - long download time on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, download, ubuntu-server

I've created my own "file hosting" on my Ubuntu 22.04 server. I made it using node.js and express.js. When I want to send a file as a response to the user using res.download(), the file download is very slow (100-500 kBps), what should I do?

i tried to fix it by adding the file to `<a href="" download>` but the effect is the same